# Parameters for optimizing interpolation in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, interpolation, kriging, parameters, inverse-distance-weighted

Is there any criteria to know the most proper parameters for an interpolation method in ArcGIS (such as, for IDW: Neighbors (min and max), sector type, semiaxis length, angle, search neighborhood)?

Any documentation with answers?

Answer (score 2):

I find the textbook that gives the best definition and discussion is:

Principles of Geographical Information Systems (Spatial Information Systems) Paperback – April 9, 1998 by Peter A. Burrough Rachael A. McDonnell

I seem to remember a trial dataset of flooding on the Netherlands as well to play with.

Comment: Well, since I consider more manageable and understandable the IDW method, and in view of the lack of time for the project I am working on, I would be grateful for any concise reference about IDW, or also optimizing IDW in ArcGIS.
Thanks.